# Auto generate textboxs and taking their ID's

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, auto-generate

I am on this project which need to generate offer page. For example user has 5 item, every item need to take 3 parameter (manual entry text). But item count may be change. All items comes from database.At this page I have offer Id, item(s) Id, I will save offer to database row by row like this ;

Lets say user has 3 item in offer page;

Offer Id,Item Id,first parameter,second param,third param:
1,1,x,y,z ---
1,5,a,b,c ---
1,47,z,x,c

As i say before item count may be change for every case, how can i dinamicly generate those textboxs for parameters and assign their id to items to reach again in codebehind for save to database. Thank You

Comment: Your question is not clear but i would suggest to create a templated listview with textboxes and afterwards iterate through all items in the listview. Every item will have it's parameter and You can do anything with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could place your TextBoxes into a Repeater that uses the DataTable where you are storing your offers as the Repeater's DataSource. That way each row of your DataTable would be given a "row" of controls on the page.

During postback (assume this occurs via a submit button), you can step through each of the Repeater's items to retrieve the control values provided by the user.